# Preventing MATLAB's readtable function from ignoring first row of delimited text data file

Tags: matlab

I have a very similar issue as the following question that was previously asked:
[readtable on text file ignores first row which contains the column names](https://readtable%20on%20text%20file%20ignores%20first%20row%20which%20contains%20the%20column%20names)

However, in my case, the file is consistently formatted correctly. All values are separated by a single space, including the first row, which consists of the column headers. I've tried switching the spaces to tabs, but this did not fix anything.

I am simply using the following code:

```
% Get list of file names from current directory and make file name variable
filelist = ls();
filename=filelist(3,1:97);

% create table object using file name
DE_genelst_raw_CntrlMvF = readtable(filename);
```

And where I should have a table with 6 rows and 5 columns with headers, I get a 6x5 table with the column headers missing. I used the `readtable` function with a more complex delimited dataset and it correctly included the headers. So I know it should be able to work. just not sure what is wrong. If need be I can provide a copy of the file. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Nevermind I just figured out the issue

Comment: maybe put it as an answer and accept it yourself, for the benefit of others in the future?

Comment: @DavidEngel I second Nathan's thought. You should answer the question here if you got it already.